# How to make the div become a container with scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the simple code:

```
<div id="container">            

    <div id = "information">
    </div>

</div>
```

When I change the "information" to width 1000, and container width 100, the "information" become very long, but I would like to let the information div inside the div...I means, I want the container have a scroll bar, if the information's width is longer than the container. How can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for asking my question for me!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```css
#container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```css
#container
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `overflow: auto` in the stylesheet.

That said, it is almost always better to make use of the available space and not introduce small regions with their own scrollbars (which are harder to deal with with AT, and require scrolling more frequently to read)

Answer (score 3):

Or use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to limit the scrolling to just vertical or horizontal.

```css
#container { overflow-x: auto; } /* Horizontal scrolling only */
```

or

```css
#container { overflow-y: auto; } /* Vertical scrolling only */
```